# Sort the contents of a large file with low RAM

Tags: algorithm

You have a large file around 50GB containing numbers. You need to read the file, sort the contents and copy the sorted contents to another new file. 
Condition - you have only 1GB RAM on the computer. However disk space is not an issue.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/sort

Comment: `interview question I was asked and I could not answer` what is your education in "Computer Science", and what has the interview been for?

Comment: You can always adapt quicksort/mergesort to use storage instead of working memory.

Comment: Is memory swapping taken into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we sort items where all the items fit in the memory, we call it [internal sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_sort). When we sort items where items is too big to store in the memory, we call it [external sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting).

Art  of Computer Programming Vol 3: Sorting and Searching on Page 248 discuss detail algorithm for external sorting (one is merge  sort).

You also mention that file contains 50GB of numbers. Maybe there is a lot of duplicated number. You might as well using counting sort if there are a lotof duplicated.